# Flutter JSON Stringfy to get below output

Tags: flutter, dart

"{\n    "checkout": {\n        "address": "plot 123, kamloops road, Shopprite  kalingalinga",\n        "city": "Lusaka",\n        "township": "Kalingalinga",\n        "comment": "testing comment coming from the app, delete this",\n        "country": "Zambia",\n        "coupon_amount": "",\n        "coupon_code": "",\n        "currency": "ZMW",\n        "customer_id": "50",\n        "email": "do@gmail.com",\n        "first_name": "Julius",\n        "last_name": "Banda",\n        "platform": "Android App",\n        "house_no": "plot 172",\n        "land_mark": "Near Kamloops Mall",\n        "order_price": "37.00",\n        "payment_data": {\n            "status": "successful",\n            "method": "cash",\n            "amount": "32.00"\n        },\n        "payment_method": "employee",\n        "phone_number": "09996404051",\n        "products": [\n            {\n                "id": 684,\n                "customer_id": 50,\n                "products_id": 44,\n                "customer_basket_quantity": 1,\n                "final_price": 32,\n                "is_order": true,\n                "inventory_id": 53\n            }\n        ],\n        "province": "Lusaka",\n        "shipping_cost": "5.0",\n        "shipping_method": "testing Shipping",\n        "townswip": "Mtendere east"\n    }\n}"

Comment: use `jsonEncode`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
final value = json.decode("Your String");
```